# Node.js memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, memory-leaks

I have some code below that I'm using in my Express.js app to centralize some acl logic. If the function returns `true` or `false` explicitly the middleware can handle the `next` call. But if it doesn't return it's up to the authorize logic to execute `next()` whenever it's finished doing it's thing.

To avoid having to write out the error data, I want to just pass in an `error()` function that can be called, which just calls the `next` function internally.

Someone told me that this can lead to some kind of memory leaks since the `next` function is in it's own closure and referencing it from outside. I see similar techniques being used in a lot of examples online, but I'm still quite new to Node.js so wondering if there is any truth to this?

```
this.router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = {
            code: 403,
            exception: 'UnauthorizedException',
            data: {}
        },
        error = function () {
            next(err);
        },
        authorize = app.route.authorize(req, res, next, error);

    if (authorize === false) {
        next(err);
    }
    else if (authorize === true) {
        next();
    }
});
```

**EDIT:Remove variables**

```
this.router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var authorize = app.route.authorize(req, res, next, function () {
        next({
            code: 403,
            exception: 'UnauthorizedException',
            data: {}
        });
    });

    if (authorize === false) {
        next({
            code: 403,
            exception: 'UnauthorizedException',
            data: {}
        });
    }
    else if (authorize === true) {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want the authorise method to handle the `next` call? What situation would this be useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set up the middleware, the `.use()` method is called there once, the anonymous handler/middleware is written to memory once, and it's that same middleware function that gets called for each new request.

The `err` variable is instantiated every time the middleware runs, and it's a different object. Had you put it outside and into the closure scope of `.use()`, it would then be the same object.

It is then passed to `next` and `next` is very likely another middleware function that gets instantiated once and stays the same in memory which persists and grabs onto its closure access.

But then, when the `next` function finishes running, the object that `err` points to would lose its references -- it should be garbage-collected.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, if `next` is just another function. It needs to somehow have information about the current request to not interfere with other requests. Like if I call `next` it needs to know what is "next". So there is some data that needs to be stored per request I think.

Comment: There's some "invisible" code added by Express that passes the `req`, `res` etc. through. The sequence of handlers are determine by the order in which you made the `.use()` call, it's like adding callbacks to a piping sequence. At some point, each middleware call should finish, and those referenced objects would lose their references and get garbage-collected; even if you reference them in the `next` middleware, at some point that next function should also terminate.